How to enable dynamic creation of sensors from mqtt
Is something like this possible?
I have several temperature sensors that send data to the topic
sensor/temp/<sensor id>
I would like home_assistant to dynamically create sensors for each sensor_id
mqtt:
  sensor:
    - state_topic: "sensor/temp/(+)"
      name: "MQTT Temperature Sensor {{$1}}"
      unit_of_measurement: "°C"
      value_template: "{{ value }}"
      device_class: temperature
      unique_id: "mqtt_sensor_{{$1}}"

The sensors do not support discovery
